# Android FlexboxLayout usage

Tags: android, android-flexboxlayout

I have created a simple application having a sequence of child Views using LinearLayout with orientation="horizontal", and manually calculate the device width and once the child item cross the device width, then i am changing the height to hold the child item in the next line.

But now android has introduced FlexboxLayout, can i replace the existing LinearLayout with FlexboxLayout?

Yes, replacing the CustomLinearLayout with FlexboxLayout works fine. Here is the Code.

***build.gradle***

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.5'
}
```

***layout.xml***

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/flexboxlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:alignItems="stretch"
    app:alignContent="stretch"
    app:layout_flexGrow="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 0"/>

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

***Activity.java***

```
private FlexboxLayout flexboxLayout;
flexboxLayout = (FlexboxLayout)findViewById(R.id.flexboxlayout);
int prevTextViewId = R.id.btn_one;
        for(int k=1; k<20; k++)
        {
            Button button = new Button(context);            
            button.setText("Button "+k);

            int curTextViewId = prevTextViewId + 1;

            final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, prevTextViewId);
            button.setLayoutParams(params);
            flexboxLayout.addView(button, params);
            prevTextViewId = curTextViewId;
        }
```

Comment: Yes. sure you can.

Comment: ok Thanks for your feedback, i will replace the layout and try it